# Sequence $\left\{ x_{n}\right\} _{n\geq1}$ s.t $\left|x_{n+1}-x_{n}\right|<2^{-n}$ for all $n\geq N$ , does this imply convergence?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Suppose $\left\{ x_{n}\right\} _{n\geq1}$
  is a sequence of real numbers and there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$
  such that $\left|x_{n+1}-x_{n}\right|<2^{-n}$
  for all $n\geq N$
 , does this imply convergence?

I know that $\lim\limits _{n\to\infty}\left|x_{n+1}-x_{n}\right|=0$
  does not imply Cauchy and thus can't imply convergence but I'm not sure if requiring that $\left|x_{n+1}-x_{n}\right|<2^{-n}$
  eventually is stronger than requiring that $\lim\limits _{n\to\infty}\left|x_{n+1}-x_{n}\right|=0$
 .

Thanks!

Comment: Somehow reminds me of the proof of Banach Fixed Point Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Show by induction on $d$ that $|x_{n+d}-x_n|<2^{1-n}$

Comment: How do you intent to perform the induction step here? The first thing that comes to mind is using $|x_{n+d+1}-x_n| \leq |x_{n+d+1}-x_{n+d}| + |x_{n+d}-x_n| < 2^{-n-d} + 2^{1-n}$ but this fails. If we change it slightly to $|x_{n+d}-x_n| \leq \left[1-2^{-d}\right]2^{1-n}$ then this approach goes through.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does since if $m,n\geq N$ (suppose $m\geq n$)
$$|x_m-x_n|\leq |x_{m+1}-x_m|+...+|x_{n+1}-x_n|\leq \frac{1}{2^m}+...+\frac{1}{2^n}=\frac{1}{2^n}\cdot \frac{1-\frac{1}{2^{m-n+1}}}{\frac{1}{2}}\leq \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$$
and thus, it's a cauchy sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does, let $n>m$, notice $|x_n-x_m|\leq\sum\limits_{i=n+1}^m|x_i-x_{i-1}|$ by the triangle inequality.

On the other hand $\sum\limits_{i=n+1}^m|x_i-x_{i-1}|\leq \sum\limits_{i=n+1}^m\frac{1}{2^{i-1}}<\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$.

So take $N$ so that $\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}<\epsilon$.

---

In general, if $\sum\limits_{i=k}^\infty |x_i-x_{i-1}|$ converges for every $k$ and $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\sum\limits_{i=k}^\infty |x_i-x_{i-1}|=0$ then the sequence is a cauchy sequence.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think you need to replace a $2^{n-1}$ with $2^{1-n}$ in the last line before the edit.

Comment: Oh yes, my bad. thanks.