# Proving that a sequence converges (boundedness)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits, cauchy-sequences

**I know that this is a cauchy sequence. But I am interested in what I wrote in line 8 to 12. I was wondering if it was correct at all? I am trying to learn the bounded sequences proof**

We assume that the terms of a sequence ${S_n}$ satisfy this property $\forall n$

$$|a_{n+1}-a_n| \leq \Big| \frac{1}{2^n} \Big| $$

**Now I would like to show that $\{a_n\}$ converges. Specifically towards** $0$

As $ \ n \longrightarrow \infty \ \text{,  we have }  \dfrac{1}{2^n} \longrightarrow 0$

Also $|a_{n+1}-a_n| \geq 0$

**So we have, as** $ \  n \longrightarrow \infty$

$$\text{(line 8) }\hspace{1cm} 0 \leq |a_{n+1}-a_n|  \leq 0$$

$$\implies \hspace{1.2cm} \ 0 \leq |a_n - a_{n+1}|  \leq 0$$
*by triangle ineq.*

$$\implies \hspace{1.2cm} 0 \leq |a_n| - |a_{n+1}|  \leq 0 $$

$$\text{(line 12) } \implies \hspace{0.2cm} \ 0 \hspace{.2cm} \leq \hspace{.2cm}|a_n| \hspace{.2cm} \leq \hspace{.2cm}0$$

Can I use this to say that this sequence is bounded and thus converge to $0$

Note: To be honest, I feel this is correct but I am not satisfied with the argument.

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1634902/42969

Comment: Unfortunately, your argument makes no sense. Note that $0 \leq |a_{n+1}-a_n|  \leq 0$ would already imply that the sequence is constant. Have a look at the referenced Q&As for correct solutions.

Comment: @MartinR Yeah, that's what I suspected. Do you have an example for the Prop: 

if  $a_n$ and $b_n$ converge to $L$ with $a_n \leq c_n \leq b_n$, then $c_n \longrightarrow L$.

Comment: That is useless here. You have $0 \le |a_{n+1}-a_n| \leq \frac{1}{2^n} $ for all $n$. From the “squeeze theorem” you can only conclude that $|a_{n+1}-a_n |\to 0$. But that does not guarantee convergence of the sequence, and it does not imply that $0 \leq |a_{n+1}-a_n|  \leq 0$ for all $n$.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Set $S_n=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{2^k}$. It's a convergent sequence. Moreover, $$|a_n-a_m|\leq |S_n-S_m|.$$

I let you conclude.

---

Notice that there is no reason that $(a_n)$ converges to $0$.

Comment: $\forall \epsilon > 0, \  \exists \ N \in \mathbb{N} \ \ s.t. \  \dfrac{1}{2^N} < \epsilon$

$|a_n-a_m|\leq |S_n-S_m| = \dfrac{1}{2^{m+1}}\big[1+ \dfrac{1}{2} + ...+ \dfrac{1}{2^{n-m-1}} \big] = \dfrac{1}{2^{m+1}} \cdot 2 = \dfrac{1}{2^m} \leq \dfrac{1}{2^N}  < \epsilon $


$$\text{Ergo } \big(a_n\big) \text{ is Cauchy} $$